# jQuery code malfunction

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm building my website and i'm running into some problems… For the landing page i want to make this thing where you have to enter a PW to get in, so i have a text input and beside it there are two divs with 50% width, one floated to the left and the other to the right.

I want it so that when the PW is entered and the RETURN key is entered, the input would fade, and the divs that were behind it would slide to their respective sides.

This works fine. But when I then click the Close button, I want them the two divs to slide back in and return back to their original position.  Well, i tried it on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/angus/pen/GjEaOo) and worked ok, but when i migrated it to [my site](http://angusweb.pw) it kinda went crazy. Here is the [repository for my website](https://github.com/dangus21/dangus21.github.io).

the html:

```
<div class="input-div">
    <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>   
        <input id="secret" type="password" />
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left to-hide"></div>
    <div class="right to-hide"></div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
    <button>Close</button>
</div>
```

the css:

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}

.left {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-right: 1px solid #111;
}

.right {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    float:right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-left: 1px solid #111;
}

.input-div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:99;
}

input {
    width:300px;
    height:50px;    
    font-size:3em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.fa-lock {
    font-size:3em;
    color:white; 
}

.container2 {
    background-color:crimson;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}

button {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

and the jQuery:

```
$('.right , .left').show();

$(function() {
    $('input').keypress(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            if (!$(this).val()) { //if it is blank. 
                alert('Denied');
            } else {
                $('.input-div').fadeOut();
                $('.to-hide').animate({
                        width: "0"
                    },
                    1000,
                    function() {
                        $('.container').hide();
                    });
            }
        }
    });
});

$('button').click(function() {
    $('.container').show();
    $('.input-div').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.to-hide').animate({width: "50%" }, 1000, function() {});
});
```

Comment: The codepen version and the version on your site give me the exact same output. They are both not working.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the difference.

Comment: They seem to be working fine for me.  No difference between the Codepen and your site.

Comment: http://www.giphy.com/gifs/l2SpRoQgXQsq3uSty this is what happens to me guys… Regardless, is there anyway i can improve the code??

Comment: what do you want it to do differently?

Comment: when i tap close, the hidden divs seem to come from the upper left corner… i would like to make them slide sideways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your repository you are calling a function on your `show()` method that's what's causing the effect that it looks like the div's are sliding from the upper left corner.

You need to **do this** on your websites `script.js`:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.container-b').show();
    $('.input-div').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.to-hide').animate({width: "50%" }, 1000);
});
```

instead of

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('.container-b').show(function(){


        $('.to-hide').animate({width: "50%" }, 1000, function() {

            $('.input-div').fadeIn(1500);

        });
    });
});
```

Here is a codepen example: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xEXLbV)

Comment: i tried it, http://www.giphy.com/gifs/d3pWSQYwo5IFa144, now the divs dont come back

Comment: Oh sorry forgot to add a ; after $('.container-b').show()

Comment: after clicking the close button, the container-b is still hidden, but it works sometimes when the element inspector is open

Comment: You are calling <script src="/js/script.js"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"> twice, use only one of each.

Comment: Ayee, glad to hear buddy.. Please accept this answer to close this question and help me aswell :)